# BOOL values not recognized on CoreData objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, boolean, nsnumber

I encountered a strange problem regarding CoreData and boolean values:
In my data model I have set an entity's property to BOOL. Later I set `theEntity.theBooleanValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` and save the object. So far so good, but when I try to check for the saved property's value with `if ([theObject valueForKey:@"theBooleanValue"] == [NSNumber numberBOOL:NO]){//do something}` it never jumps into the if clause. But if I check for `== [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]` its working... so basically I try to save a bool but it's recognized as an int... Any ideas what's going on there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes more sense to examine `[[theObject valueForKey:@"theBooleanValue"] boolValue]` for me. i.e.,

```
if(![[theObject valueForKey:@"theBooleanValue"] boolValue])
{
    // Your code
}
```

I think `==` operator compares the object pointer, and not the number itself. To compare number there is a separete method `[NSNumber isEqualToNumber:]`.

Comment: This is exactly it - the `==` operator is wrong for this comparison.

Comment: Thanks, using `[NSNumber isEqualToNumber:]` was indeed the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Note, that'll make your life a lot easier of you declare the properties like

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL theBooleanValue;
```

This will allow you to use

```
if (!theObject.theBooleanValue) {
    // Your code here
}
```

And you can assign directly with

```
theObject.theBooleanValue = YES;
```